# Custom shell script can't be found

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew

I am running MacOSX Sierra and have `homebrew` installed. So I'm trying to create `compress-slide.sh` script under `~/bin`. In order for me to get rid of doing symlinks I added the `~/bin` in my path so my path looks like this now: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/bin`

I've set the path under `/etc/paths` and here is how it looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~/bin
```

But when I try `which compress-slide.sh` nothing is found, it doesn't give me the path I'm expecting which is `~/bin/compress-slide.sh` I just wish to use this script when I'm on different directories. Also I made sure that I'm the owner of the script and that it has executable permission.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dummyuser  dummyuser   135B Dec 28 18:13 compress-slide.sh
```

Here's the content of my script, just a simple command to test it works;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'test'
```

Here is my `homebrew` config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.1.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 9cd5a21b473f0271b162bbe7f77f7d1468c0cfa1
Last commit: 2 weeks ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 797542c1bf61c4cfc58c7a52a2534d154cc584d1
Core tap last commit: 8 days ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: octa-core 64-bit ivybridge
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
Clang: 8.0 build 800
Git: 2.10.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_60, 1.7.0_79
macOS: 10.12.2-x86_64
Xcode: 8.2.1
CLT: N/A
X11: N/A
```

Is this because of `Homebrew` conflicting with my setup? Has anyone encountered this as well?

Comment: No, it's because you have a `~` in your PATH. Please use `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/bin` instead.

Comment: @patrix Thank you very much! I just spelled it out and it works!

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with being lazy. The path_helper application prevents tilde and variable expansion. Here's a modified `/private/etc/paths` file.

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
~/bin
$HOME/local/bin
```

The `path_helper`application constructs a string to be evaluated in `/private/etc/profile` using the current PATH variable along with those directories listed `/private/etc/paths` and files within `/private/etc/paths.d`.

```
/usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/bin:\$HOME/local/bin"; export PATH;
```

The double quotes around the PATH variable prevent tilde expansion and the backslash before the dollar sign prevent variable expansion of $HOME.

Comment: Awesome I think this answers the question directly. Thanks!

Comment: Well done and excellent answer cutting to the direct cause of the path pain. +lots of votes I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I would sym link the scripts you place out of the path to /usr/local/bin so you don't need to reason with ~ expansion in .dot files for your shell.

It's possible to have a durable way to ensure your enviroment is set up to handle ~ - but I'm a fan of having absolute paths there to avoid problems when you `su` to other users and have environment cross contamination as well as issues like you face.

This isn't anything about `homebrew` - purely about `bash` or whatever shell you are using.

Comment: also - apologies for basically saying "do the thing you said at the top you didn't want to do" by adding sym links - but they're really useful for the case you mention above. My suspicion is Patrix or another will get you a proper answer rather than my advice to punt on this one. : - )

Comment: Thank you very much! I think should be stop being lazy and spell out the path if I can.

Comment: Just a follow up question, how would you sym link an entire folder for example the `/Users/username/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` as you were proposing? I know I can do `ln -s /Users/username/bin/* /usr/local/bin` but the problem with this approach is I'd have to do it every single time whenever I have new script?

Comment: No way to do that, you'd have to make a script to iterate over the folder and link / clean up as needed. In that case, fixing the path is probably worth the pain for that case.

Comment: hmm if that's the case then I'd probably stick with including my home `bin` in the path. I can deal with `.dot` files in it assuming they are just bunch of `.DS_Store` ones. Thank you again for your help.